# Pass variable from Jquery to Node to run a git command

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

I have a dropdown list which contains the name of the branches in a html file.
I want to take that name and insert it into below node code so that every single time a user clicks a value in dropdown, it should pass it to node and run the command "git log BRANCHNAME" and store it Json (for now):

```
var sys = require('sys')
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('handle', function(request,response,error){
var branchName = request.body.branchname;
console.log("Branch name"+branchName+"");
 if(error){
console.log("error");
 }
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var fs = require('fs');

  function put(error, stdout, stderr) { 
   var commitsbybranch = JSON.stringify(stdout.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(e) { return e.substring(0);}).filter(function(e) { return e; }));
  fs.writeFile('reacted/testcommitsbybranch.json', commitsbybranch);
   }
  exec("git log "+branchName+"", put);
  console.log("Pulling commits by branch done");
  }  )


   app.listen(3000);
```

My Jquery code is this so when I click the option I want the value to be passed to above node code

```
        $.getJSON("Branches.json", function (data) {
                  $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $('#users-dropdown').append(
                           $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item)
          );
     });

});
```

I also need to have proper format of JSON, If I could get help with that too please
I need to split each object with right braces.

Comment: How are you intending to get the data from the webpage to the Node code? Do you have a REST service of some kind?

Comment: No I don't.  I just have html page and jquery code, and then node. But none of it is connected together

Comment: You can't connect HTML code with Node without setting up a server of some kind - they run entirely separately.

Comment: So how can I do this?

Comment: I agree with @JoeClay... But you can try nodegit for use git from nodejs

Comment: @Gill - I would recommend reading up on the Express.js library and learning about REST services. You basically need to create a web server, then use AJAX in the browser to send the data to it.

Comment: And yes, I agree with @LeandroWilliam - you're much better off using a Git library to run Git commands. Executing user input on the server's command line seems like it could easily cause security issues!

Comment: Could you briefly give me an example, as I am really new to all this. I looked at express js, I will install that module

Comment: So I install express, then how would express work in node, or how would it get variables

Comment: How can i link res to the option the I click on resvar app = express();


app.get('/', function(req,res,next){

 next();
})

Comment: You'd need to create a `app.post` route, and send HTTP POST requests to it. The body of the request will then show up in `req.body` (although watch out - you need to have the [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) library installed too for this to work).

Comment: I have edited the code, but it's not working, What else can I do it

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the `change` event in the `<select>` tag and send the selected branch to the server. Then in the server create a `route` to catch the request sended from the client (with the branchname) and do your logic. This is an example:

server:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/handle.html'));
});


app.post('/handle', function(request, response, next){
    var branchName = request.body.branchname;
    console.log("Branch name"+branchName+"");

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;


    function put(error, stdout, stderr) {
        var commitsbybranch = JSON.stringify(stdout.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(e) { return e.substring(0);}).filter(function(e) { return e; }));
        fs.writeFile('reacted/testcommitsbybranch.json', commitsbybranch);
    }
    exec("git log "+branchName+"", put);
    console.log("Pulling commits by branch done");
});


app.listen(3000);
```

the code:

```
app.post('/handle', function(request, response, next){
...
})
```

is when we process the client request. Note the use of the `middleware` `body-parser` to get the variables in the `body` attribute.

The client code (`handle.html`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Git Branches</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#users-dropdown').change(function(){
                var branch = $("#users-dropdown option:selected").text();
                $.post('handle', {branchname: branch}, function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });

            $.getJSON("branches.json", function (data) {
                $.each(data.branches, function (index, item) {
                    $('#users-dropdown').append($('<option>', {value: item.branch, text: item.branch}));
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="users-dropdown">
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we send the request to the server after a `<option>` is selected:

```
$('#users-dropdown').change(function(){
    var branch = $("#users-dropdown option:selected").text();
    $.post('handle', {branchname: branch}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The `branches.json` is in the `public` folder. With this line: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` we make everything inside the `public` folder available for the clients. This is how the `branches.jason` file looks:

```
{
    "branches": [
                    {
                        "branch": "branch1"
                    },
                    {
                        "branch": "branch2"
                    },
                    {
                        "branch": "branch3"
                    },
                    {
                        "branch": "branch4"
                    }
                ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting errors on my HTML page, now the json doesn't load. But my json file is like this ["master","branch1","branch2"]

Comment: It says branches.json  not found and its in the same folder structure

Comment: If you have the `branches.json` file in the root of the `public` folder it should work, but if the file is deeper in the folder structure you have to explicitly specify the path e.g: if the file is in 'public/json/branches.json' the correct path is 'json/branches.json' in `$.getJSON('json/branches.json', ...)`. `public` folder is the root for all your static assets and is assumed that is in the root of your app.

Comment: It works now, but when I click on the item in my dropdown nothing happens, it doesn't run the command ` exec("git log "+branchName+"", put);`

Comment: make sure that you have a git repo in the root of the app and the proper branches. Also check the file `testcommitsbybranch.json` in the folder `reacted`.

Comment: you may consider using any of the modules to work with git in `nodejs` e.g: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit